# copy the file from host to docker container prior to run webserver in container

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

i have a nodejs app within docker container. i run a docker container with a v flag and map some host folder to a docker folder, say /opt on host is mapped to /opt on docker instance. than the docker runs a `node app.js` and an application is up and running, however before i run `node app.js` i would like to copy the file */opt/kuku.txt* inside the container to another folder */var/src/application/etc/*. should i do it in Dockerfile just before `CMD` directive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that in the Dockerfile... the file isn't there yet at image build time.  It apparently lives on your web server at deploy time.

You could solve this in a couple ways...

Create a simlink in your container that points to the location where the file WILL live at runtime...

```
# Dockerfile
RUN ln -s /var/src/application/etc/kuku.txt /opt/kuku.txt
```

Second, you could just bind mount the file at runtime to the correct location...

```
docker run -v /opt:/opt -v /opt/kuku.txt:/var/src/application/etc/kuku.txt myimage
```

Third, you could add an entrypoint to your container that handles this

```
# entrypoint.sh
cp /opt/kuku.txt:/var/src/application/etc/kuku.txt
exec node server

# Dockerfile

...
COPY entrypoint.sh /app/entrypoint.sh
CMD [entrypoint.sh]
```